# Background listener for pollfish survey availability for android

Tags: java, android, background, listener, survey

I'm a new android developer so excuse me if i ask too much. The thing is i would like you to write me an example of the way i could listen, in background, for survey availability of pollfish (sdk documentation here: https://www.pollfish.com/android) using a service or something.

I've tried searching for background listeners in google but the only thing i found was about location background listeners.

Edit:(He means to say is there a way to listen for survey availability even in the background when app is closed, and he can! by using background task and the alarm manager, if someone can, link to the answer will also help✌).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you want to have somebody write your code for you ("i would like you to write me an example"), please hire a consultant. Otherwise, please explain what you tried and what specific problems that you encountered. Or, explain what you think is different about whatever the Pollfish API exposes compared to using a `LocationListener`, so we can explain how to address those differences.

Comment: Ok sorry, could you show me how can i implement a listener in a service? Is it the same as location listener?